# May I redirect 2 different domains to different pages inside 1 WordPress installation?

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, admin, domain-name

I have 2 domains:

[www.domain-1.com](http://www.domain-1.com)

[www.domain-2.com](http://www.domain-2.com)

I installed WordPress on the web hosting service's server into public_html folder. [www.domain-1.com](http://www.domain-1.com) redirects to public_html folder. I created Hungarian pages, and an English page, which is not linked into the nav menu. Can I somehow configure WordPress, that the other domain ([www.domain-2.com](http://www.domain-2.com)) would redirect to the English page (which is in the same folder, the same WP installation)?

So my point is that I want to manage both the English and Hungarian versions of the site on the same dashboard, the same WP installation, and the first domain to point at the Hungarian sites, the second domain to point to the English sites. Or is it necessary to create another folder (for the second domain name to point at) and create another WP installation there and handle the Hungarian and English sites on a separate admin interface? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: When you say, _"I also created an English page"_, what _exactly_ does that mean? Are you using any WP multi-language plugins to begin with? If not yet, then that is probably the first thing you should look into.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question. I have created Hungarian and English pages inside 1 WP installation.  I want the HU domain to point at Hungarian pages, and the EU domain to point at English pages, but still every page rest in the same folder, the same WP installation. Is this possible or I have to create 2 separate WP installations?

Comment: Is you taking user input to change the language or other logic like ip address to switch to domains ?

Comment: Yes, that can be done using one installation. As I said, go look into multi-language plugins. https://www.wpbeginner.com/showcase/9-best-translation-plugins-for-wordpress-websites/

Comment: Either use multilang plugin , wait for wordpress 6.0 when we hope to get multilang built-in or create wordpress multisite https://wordpress.org/support/article/create-a-network/
You can have 1 dashboard with 2 domains as 1 is considered as primary. This solution requires more maintaince if both websites have differences.

Comment: You misunterstand me. I do have 2 domains. Actually I want 2 different sites, with 2 different domains pointing to each of them (www.domain.eu and www.domain.hu). May I manage this from one admin, 1 WP installation or I have to install WP twice in different sub-directories and direct the domains to the different directories?

Comment: https://translatepress.com/wordpress-multisite-multilingual/ and https://learnwoo.com/wordpress-multisite-for-multilingual-sites/, I think this will helps you, please check

Comment: Thank you, I have solved it meanwhile. I created a sub-directory for the EN page and redirected the .eu domain to this folder and installed WordPress again with different login credentials. So there will be different dashboards for the two pages, they will be handled separately. Anyway, thank you for your help!